# Given name marked as FNU on old passport but given on new passport, is this a problem for a valid US visa?

Tags: visas, usa

My mom’s old passport has only a Surname and no Given Name. The USA Visa was also issued this way.

Example:

- Surname: Lakshmi Vishnu
- Given Name: FNU

My mom’s new passport has changed the way the information is structured.

Example:

- Surname: Vishnu
- Given Name: Lakshmi

The old visa is still Valid and she is visiting me next month. She has traveled to the US before.

Will this change of surname and given name pose a problem?